# React Functional Component - useState / useCallback - value changes back / reverts to initial value on submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a functional component where I am submitting a text value entered by the user.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react'
// other imports

function Settings (props) {

const [primaryColor, setPrimaryColor] = useState('#E02E26');

useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`//URL`, {...})
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(
            (result) => {
                setPrimaryColor(result.primaryColor);
            })
},[]);

const handlePrimaryColorChange = useCallback((newValue) => {
    setPrimaryColor(newValue);
}, []);

const handlePCChange = useCallback((newValue) => {
    setPrimaryColor(newValue.hex)
}, []);

const handleSubmit = useCallback((_event) => {
        fetch(`//URL`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify({
            primaryColor: primaryColor
        })})
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((result) => {
                console.log('response recieved from post api');
            })
  }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <Page title="Customise UI">
                <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <TextField type="text" onChange={handlePrimaryColorChange} value={primaryColor} />

                    <SketchPicker disableAlpha={true} color={primaryColor} onChangeComplete={handlePCChange}/>

                    <Button primary submit>Save Settings</Button>
                </Form>
            </Page>
        </div>
    )

Settings.getInitialProps = async (context) => {
    return context.query;
}
```

The data is correctly loaded by 'useEffect' and 'primaryColor' is set and the correct values are displayed on TextField and SketchPicker components.

When I change values in either TextField and SketchPicker then the value gets updated on-screen in the other component correctly.

Now, when I click on Submit, the value that is received on the backend or if I print it just before fetch is '#E02E26' (the initial value in useState). The fetch request is successful.

What is going wrong here? I want to send the current primaryColor value in the fetch body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `primaryColor` to the array:

```js
const handleSubmit = useCallback((_event) => {
    fetch(`//URL`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
    body: JSON.stringify({
        primaryColor: primaryColor
    })})
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((result) => {
        console.log('response recieved from post api');
    })
}, [primaryColor]);
```